# Cast produces 'Returned type character varying does not match expected type character varying(8)'

Tags: database, postgresql, types, plpgsql, varchar

Yesterday we had a PostgreSQL database upgraded to version 9.1.3. We thought we had everything tested and ready, but there is a function we missed. It returns a table type like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(
  patient_number varchar,
  tumor_number_param varchar,
  facility_number varchar
)
RETURNS SETOF patient_for_registrar
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY          
     
  SELECT cast(nfa.patient_id_number as varchar),
  ...
```

I only only give the first column of the select because that is where the error happens. Before today this function ran fine, but now it gives this error:

> ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
> Detail: Returned type character varying does not match expected type
> character varying(8) in column 1.   Where: PL/pgSQL function
> "getwebregistrarpatient_withdeletes" line 3 at RETURN QUERY [SQL
> State=42804]

The column `nfa.patient_id_number` is text and is being cast for the column `patient_id_number` in `patient_for_registrar` that is `varchar(8)`. After reading about this some I think the problem is because the column length isn't being specified when casting from text. But the problem is I've tried various combinations of substrings to fix this and none are solving the problem:

```
substring(cast(nfa.patient_id_number as varchar) from 1 for 8),

cast(substring(nfa.patient_id_number from 1 for 8) as varchar),

cast(substring(nfa.patient_id_number from 1 for 8) as varchar(8)),
```

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your function ..

```
RETURNS SETOF patient_for_registrar
```

The returned row type must match the declared type exactly. You did not disclose the definition of `patient_for_registrar`, probably the associated composite type of a table. I quote the manual about [Declaration of Composite Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html#AEN7213):

> Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically
>   created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row
>   type.

If the first column of that type (table) is defined `varchar(8)` (with length modifier) - as the error message indicates, you have to return `varchar(8)` with the same length modifier; `varchar` won't do. It is irrelevant for that matter whether the string length is only 8 characters, the **data type** has to match.

[`varchar`, `varchar(n)` and `varchar(m)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) are *different* data types for PostgreSQL.

Older versions did not enforce the type modifiers, but [with PostgreSQL **9.0** this was changed for plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-0.html#AEN109477):

> PL/pgSQL now requires columns of composite results to match the
>   expected type modifier as well as base type (Pavel Stehule, Tom Lane)
>
> For example, if a column of the result type is declared as
>   NUMERIC(30,2), it is no longer acceptable to return a NUMERIC of some
>   other precision in that column. Previous versions neglected to check
>   the type modifier and would thus allow result rows that didn't
>   actually conform to the declared restrictions.

#### Two basic ways to fix your problem:

- You can cast the returned values to match the definition of `patient_for_registrar`:

  ```
  nfa.patient_id_number::varchar(8)
  ```
- Or you can change the `RETURNS` clause. I would use [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) and declare a matching composite type. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726103/939860).

  ```
  RETURNS TABLE (patient_for_registrar varchar, col2 some_type, ...)
  ```

As an aside: I *never* use `varchar` if I can avoid it - especially not with length modifier. It offers hardly anything that the type `text` couldn't do. If I *need* a length restriction, I use a column constraint which can be changed without rewriting the whole table.

Comment: Interesting... patient_for_registrar is a table created just for this function's return type. The column in question is this: patient_id_number varchar(8). Your first suggestion is exactly where I'm having trouble, casting as the appropriate type is giving me the same error. I will try your second suggestion though, maybe it will prove the more flexible solution. I'll update this once I give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: @user720956: In PostgreSQL, the system creates a composite type (row type) of the same name whenever you create a table. I amended my answer with more information and clarified a bit.

Comment: That is all great info -- I'm changing to to the table return type and it works like a charm. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: In my case I was returning a dynamic table from two different function but combining the result set as single one in .NET so one table the column was there and another one I need to return a default value so this worked perfectly.

'Default Value' :: varchar